# How to make integrations in AWS Api Gateway v2 (http) with lambda alias and stage variables in terraform

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway, alias

I have several lambdas with aliases (develop, production, staging..) and when I try to make an integration with his route like this

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "http_routes" {
  for_each = local.lambda_integrations

  api_id    = aws_apigatewayv2_api.api_http.id
  route_key = each.key

  target = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.http_integrations[each.key].id}"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "http_integrations" {
  for_each = local.lambda_integrations

  api_id              = aws_apigatewayv2_api.api_http.id
  integration_type    = "AWS_PROXY"
  integration_method  = "POST"

  integration_uri       = "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.auth.region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${module.lambdas_functions[index(module.lambdas_functions.*.function_name,each.value.lambda)].arn}:$${stageVariables.alias}/invocations"
}
```

and

```
# Main Permission
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "permission_lambda" {
  for_each = local.lambda_integrations

  statement_id  = can(each.value.statement) ? each.value.statement : "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  
  function_name = module.lambdas_functions[
    index(module.lambdas_functions.*.function_name,each.value.lambda)
  ].function_name

  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.api_http.execution_arn}/*/*"
}

# Stage develop permission
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "permission_lambda_alias_develop" {
  for_each = local.lambda_integrations

  statement_id  = can(each.value.statement) ? each.value.statement : "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  
  function_name = module.lambdas_functions[
    index(module.lambdas_functions.*.function_name,each.value.lambda)
  ].function_name

  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.api_http.execution_arn}/*/*"

  qualifier     = "develop"
}
```

this works with a [number] version in CloudWatch, but in the lambda trigger I get this:

[image]
[image]

and although the code works, it does not seem to me to be correct.

what could be the best and correct approach to this situation?.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is this:

1. Destroyed the API Gateway components (used target)

   `terraform destroy --var-file VAR_FILES --target API_AND_LAMBDA_MODULES`
2. Renamed the stage to "$default"
3. Made the value of the **perm_source_arn** parameter as
   `"arn:aws:execute-api:${REGION}:${ACCOUNT_ID}:${API_ID}/*/*${ROUTE_KEY_PATH}"`

After these, just re-apply.